# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy219 cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.redis.connection.StringRedisConnection

Tags: java, spring, proxy, redis, cglib

This is a function for redis, pipeline. It used before, but today when I test this function. It not works.

```
public List<Object> hgetpipeline(List<String> keys) {
        List<Object> results = redisTemplate.executePipelined(
                new RedisCallback<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
                        StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn = (StringRedisConnection)connection;
                        for(int i=0; i< keys.size(); i++) {
                            stringRedisConn.hGetAll(keys.get(i)+"");
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });
      return results;
    }
```

Some error happening in this line

```
StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn = (StringRedisConnection)connection;
```

There is error info

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy219 cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.redis.connection.StringRedisConnection
```

annonation in main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true, exposeProxy = true)
@EnableScheduling
@RestController
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Server started!";
    }

}
```

Comment: If it works before, is somethings have not changed in your conifg ? such as introduction of new libraries ? have you try to clean the project ?

Comment: i am sorry for this code is changed so much .so I can not compare this project with before

Answer (score 1):

you must use stringRedisTemplate.
for example:

```
@Resource
private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

public List<Object> hgetpipeline(List<String> keys) {
    List<Object> results = stringRedisTemplate.executePipelined(
            new RedisCallback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
                    StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn = (StringRedisConnection)connection;
                    for(String key:keys) 
                    {
                        stringRedisConn.get(key);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public List<Object> hgetpipeline(List<String> keys) {
        List<Object> results = redisTemplate.executePipelined(
                new RedisCallback<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {

                        for(int i=0; i< keys.size(); i++) {
                            redisTemplate.hGetAll(keys.get(i)+"");
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });
      return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just use connection rather than redisTemplate in  method doInRedis.

```
public List<Object> hgetpipeline(List<String> keys) {
    int i = 0;
    List<Object> results = redisTemplate.executePipelined(
            new RedisCallback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
                    return connection.hGetAll(keys.get(i++).getBytes());
                }
            });
  return results;
}
```